# ng-hide show on-click event in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have in my index.html a div which initially must be hidden:

```
<div class="autocomplete" ng-show="div_show" ng-controller="SearchController">
```

And I need when I click on my Menu on the search link,the div to be shown,basically

```
ng-show="true"
```

So on my link I defined something like that:

```
<a class="list-group-item"  ng-click="show()"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Search</a>
```

And in my controller the function :

```
$scope.div_show = false;
$scope.show =function(){
    $scope.div_show = true;
    console.log($scope.div_show);
    alert($scope.div_show);


}
```

When I click on the link I have the alert value set to 'true'but the div is still hidden,

Any suggestions? Thank you!!!

Comment: different controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle the `ng-show` element, just assign the following directive on the Menu button:

```
ng-click="div_show = !div_show"
```

All this does is toggles the value of `div_show` between `true` and `false`.

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bH3LeuUeK84Qlfr6F8oh?p=preview) for a full demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item"  ng-click="div_show = true">
     <i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Search
 </a>
```

This will make sure the page is not getting loaded again and i will set the div_show to be true, only if it is in the scope.